# Define Sessions not only with time limit

Tags: sql

I've been trying to group an events-like table (user, action, event_time) into sessions .

But the common "idle time" approach is not enough.

I need to check if the user was idle for more than an period X of time (ok), BUT if the user started the game, then it will very likely be idle for a long time and every action between start game and end game, regardless of the time interval, should not be considered a new session. But when the game finishes, a new session shows up:

For example (idle time 5 min)

```
| action        | user | event_at     | new_session? (desired output) |
|---------------|------|--------------|-------------------------------|
| random1       | 1    | 1 sec        | 1                             |
| random3       | 1    | 30 sec       | 0                             |
| random4       | 1    | 6:00 min     | 1                             |
| random5       | 1    | 7:00  min    | 0                             |
| game_started  | 1    | 7:30 min     | 0                             |
| random2       | 1    | 20:00 min    | 0                             |
| random5       | 1    | 27:00 min    | 0                             |
| game_finished | 1    | 35:00 min    | 0                             |
| random5       | 1    | 35:30 min    | 1                             |
```

The problem are those random actions between the game_start and game_finish. I cannot tell SQL to ignore them and not count them as a new session when using the idle time logic (- that is needed for the part not between start and finish).

in "proper" programming language I could just add a flag after the "for" or "while" finds "game started" and tell it to ignore anything until "game_finished" is found. But in SQL this is simply not that easy, even using an auxiliary column.

Any Ideas ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should show your current query.

Answer (score 0):

Identify the games *first*, then use `lag()` for the session start:

```
  select t.*,
         (case when in_game > 0 and
                    (lag(in_game) over (order by time) is null or
                     lag(in_game) over (order by time) = 0
                    )
               then 1
               when in_game = 0 and
                    (lag(time) over (partition by in_game order by time) is null or
                     lag(time) over (partition by in_game order by time) < time - interval '5 minute'
                    )
               then 1
               else 0
           end) as new_session
  from (select t.*,
               sum(case when action = 'game_start' then 1
                        when action = 'game_end' then -1
                   end) over (order by time) as in_game
        from t
       ) t;
```

This does not handle every edge case.  For instance, this version does not handle nested games.  It might also be tricky with games right next to each other.  But I think it does do what you want.

Comment: Hi Gordon this already gives me some light. Many thanks. Now I have to deal with the exceptions cases. For example, since the table is a snapshot from an datetime interval, I may have "game_done" but not an start to it, which will give me -1 results... 

Or there might be an error where you have game started twice, but only 1 game_end (but any "game_end" should "reset" the counter)

But I sincerely think that SQL is not the proper programming language to deal with these problems

Comment: @maria_saiz . . . It is possible.  I would suggest that you ask another question with more appropriate sample data and desired results.  It really is only possible to answer the question that you ask, and your data is a bit messier than this question suggests.